# Sublime editor: how to force all files to use spaces or tabs?

Tags: sublimetext3, editor, sublimetext

I use Sublime 3.0 editor and my editor switches to `Spaces: 2` for any *.vue file and if I open a JS file, it switches to `Tab: 4`.  This is causing issues with my linter.  How can I set a standard for *all* files?

Answer (score 1):

```json
    // Set to false to disable detection of tabs vs. spaces on load
    "detect_indentation": true,
```

This setting defaults to being turned on, and when it is Sublime will analyze files as they're loaded to try and detect how they're indented. That will cause it to switch from using tabs to spaces if the file seems to be indented one way or the other, and for space indented files it can also adjust the `tab_width` setting as appropriate.

Turning the setting off will stop it from doing that, which will leave the settings as they are even if they don't match what the current file looks like.